# How to extract image in jar file

Tags: java, image, jar, extract

I have some jar file mobile from Gameloft.I can't see where are images.
I just see some class file and some 0, 1, 2, 3, ..., a, b, ..., x, y, z file.
I think game's images in that files.
So how can I extract it ?

Comment: Rename jar to zip, and unzip it.

Comment: Those files that do not end in `.class` might be images. Without file extension you might inspect the magic cookie of jpeg, png, gif (those are the first bytes that are always the same for the same file type). Or add .png/.gif, and try it out.

Answer (score 0):

some game companies, like gameloft, try to save their images from stealing. to do that, they modify image bytes. so, 0,1,2... probably are image files, but modified bytes. so you can not decode them with known decode functions, like createBitmap. you should decompile the code and probably it will be obfuscated. then you need to put breakpoint at some functions like, createBitmap. then check through back, how they load file and what they do just before send data to createBitmap.